# php string with double quotes echo backslash instead

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
while($this->stmt->fetch()){
                $string=$string.'","'.$idRuolo;
                $i++;
            }       
            $str= ltrim($string,',"');

      $str=stripslashes($str); 

            echo json_encode($str);
```

I have tried everything but I can't delete the backslash from the result,
this is the output:

"2\",\"1\",\"3"

this is what I want:

"2","1","3"

Comment: use like this  stripslashes(stripslashes($str));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `str_replace`.

```
$str = str_replace("\\","",$str);
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned!!

Comment: Try this code here `<?php

$str = '"2\",\"1\",\"3"';
echo str_replace("\\","",$str);
?>`
http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: I know, but in my case it doesn't work I can't understand why

Comment: What do you mean by in your case ? If this is the string you mentioned, then it must work!!

Comment: ok, I resolved, the problem was that I use echo json_encode so in json_encode the output was with the backslash

Answer (score 0):

i think this code help for you

```
<?php
function removeslashes($string)
{
    $string=implode("",explode("\\",$string));
    return stripslashes(trim($string));
}


$text="My dog don\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'t like the postman!";
echo removeslashes($text);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[stripslashes($str);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

> Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. (\' becomes ' and so
>   on.) Double backslashes (\) are made into a single backslash (\ ).

Your string contain double slash

You use

```
preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $str);
echo json_encode($str);
```